# Cómo implementar el uso de un campo de flags en mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, eficiencia, sqldatatypes

En una tabla de mysql tengo un campo que utilizo para almacentar el estado on/off de una serie de banderas/flags/parámetros. En mi caso se trata de un campo de 10bits, es decir, 10 posiciones que almacenan 0,1 en cada uno de los bits.
Bien, el campo en mysql puede almacenarse de diversas formas (entero, bit(10), char(10)).

Supongamos que la segunda posición desde la derecha la utilizo para saber, en una tabla de usuarios, si el usuario quiere o no mostrar su perfil puúblico, siendo 1(si), 0(no).

**Si quiero buscar** todos los usuarios que tienen el perfil público a la vista tendré que buscar para el caso de XXXXXXXX1X siendo X cualquier valor.

Esto lo puedo hacer en un campo tipo entero con **WHERE(FLAGS & 2)** ya que 4=b'10'. Y funciona.

También podría hacer, si el campo lo almaceno como bit **WHERE(FLAGS & b'10')** y también funciona.

Otro caso sería almacenarlo como char(10) y haría **WHERE(FLAGS & b'10' )**

Por último también podría hacer algo así **WHERE(SUBSTRING(FLAGS,9,1)=1 )**

El caso es que en todos los casos la consulta se convierte en **FULL TABLE SCAN** según me indica EXPLAIN, a pesar de tener un indice sobre dicho campo FLAGS.

Por lo tanto, teniendo en cuenta que tratamos con tablas de entorno a 100.000 registros,

¿Existe alguna solución eficiente para estos casos??

GRACIAS

Comment: Al usar una función sobre el campo flags el motor probablemente omitirá el índice. Debieras crear un campo booleano para cada flag

Comment: Ya, sin embargo en este caso tendría que crear 10 campos de tipo bit que no es problema, el problema vendría en la creación de los 10 índices asociados a cada uno y que penalizaría demasiado la ejecución de cualquier operación sobre esta tabla. Además el campo flags me permite ampliar si fuese necesario en cualquier momento sin apenas incremento de espacio de almacenamiento

Comment: puedes crear columnas virtuales generadas a partir de cada bit de tu campo flags. Esas columnas no usan almacenamiento extra ni memoria extra, y soportan índices: http://mysqlserverteam.com/indexing-json-documents-via-virtual-columns/ . De otra manera, la respuesta es que no. Los índices buscan por match exacto o por rango (si es un entero o una fecha).

Comment: En MySQL no hace falta añadir indice para campos de valor de tipo booleano, en caso de que añadas un indice y luego realizas una busqueda haciendo SUBSTRING es como sino tuvieras indice.